# Update SF Campaign Member Status Using AMPSCRIPT

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, campaign-member

I am trying to update a Campaign Member Status record using AMPSCRIPT.  I am using the following AMPSCRIPT to do this:

```
%%[ 
var @campaignmemberid,@response
set @campaignmemberid = QueryParameter('campaignmemberid')
set @response = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('CampaignMember',@campaignmemberid,'Status','Accepted')
]%%
```

I do not get any errors, the Cloudpage renders correctly and the date/time stamp on the Campaign Member record in SF gets updated, however, the Campaign Member status is not updated.  I have also tried:

```
%%[ 
var @campaignmemberid,@response
set @campaignmemberid = RequestParameter('campaignmemberid')
set @response = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('CampaignMember',@campaignmemberid,'Status','Accepted')
]%%
```

Any ideas on what is wrong with the AMPSCRIPT that would prevent the status from getting updated?

Answer (score 1):

Is the `campaignmemberid` passed correctly? Have you tried to print it with `%%=v(@campaignmemberid)=%%` to check?

Also make sure "Accepted" is included as a picklist value in you Sales Cloud.

I just faced the same issue and got it work with

```
var @mid, @campaignupdate
set @mid = Trim(RequestParameter("mid"))
set @campaignupdate = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('CampaignMember',@mid,'Status','Responded')
```